# Joining tables via PK Columns when one is CLUSTERED whereas the other is NON-CLUSTERED... Bad Idea?

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing, inner-join, clustered-index

Can it have a negative performance impact to `INNER JOIN` two tables via `PrimaryKey` columns while one table has a `CLUSTERED` Index on its `PrimaryKey` column whereas the other table has a `NON-CLUSTERED` index on its `PrimaryKey` column?

Comment: if I well understand the question, performance will depend on the fields (of the table having the non clustered index) of the select clause : are they all part of the non clustered index or not ? If not the data engine will have to load in memory the pages of index AND the pages of data.

Comment: So you say it matters whether the select clause contians the fields that are part of INDEXes?

Comment: yes that's why the [INCLUDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) instruction exists and also the notion of covering index.

Comment: By the way, as often, selection gain is insertion loss. From here it is a question of balance between reads and writes.